# Any ideas on making this window?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, interop

Hop on a Windows 7 machine and open Notepad for example. Drag the window all the way to the left. You'll notice Windows throws up a glass window on the left half of the screen to indicate docking. However, you'll notice this is not your normal Aero glass window. The glass is a lot clearer and has 45 degree "stripes" running across it. I need to duplicate this window's look *EXACTLY* (or to an indistinguishable level).

I get its a popup window
I get it takes the height of the screen
I get it takes half the width of the screen

The portion I need to duplicate is the look of the clearer glass and the 45 degree "stripes". The normal glass look is *not* close enough.

Seems like they are taking a normal aero window, making it semi transparent (not glass) and putting a semi transparent overlay on top of it.

I used reshacker to look at the aero.msstyles dll and found the png that I *think* they are using for the overlay (image #900), but I can't seem to get it to stretch the same way or look remotely similar.

Any thoughts?